# Getting errorlevel from a called batch file

Tags: batch-file

I have several batch files that I call from a parent batch file.  I need to trap if there are any errors that occur in the child batch files. When a child batch file makes a call to an exe file, I am able to trap the error in the child batch file just fine.  How do I surface it up to the parent batch file?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Exit with:

```
exit /b errorlevel
```

In your child batch script.

Comment: What about if I don't have control over my child batch script? For example, I'm calling Maven (`call mvn clean test`)

Comment: Jorn, if it is a batch script then you always have control over it. If it is an .exe not returning the right error code then ask the 3rd party to fix it.

Answer (score 4):

Using `exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%` in the called batch file should percolate it up nicely.